# MVC3 Ajax.ActionLink

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

For the following:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", "AdminGroup", new { id = item.AdminGroupId }, new AjaxOptions { Confirm = "Delete?", HttpMethod = "Delete", OnSuccess = "function() { $(this).parent().parent().remove() }" })
```

OnSuccess get's errored out. please help.
thanks

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It should be like this:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink(
    "Delete", 
    "Delete", 
    "AdminGroup", 
    new { id = item.AdminGroupId }, 
    new AjaxOptions { 
        Confirm = "Delete?", 
        HttpMethod = "Delete", 
        OnSuccess = "handleSuccess" 
    }
)
```

where you have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function handleSuccess() {
    // TODO: handle the success
    // be careful because $(this) won't be 
    // what you think it is in this callback.
}
</script>
```

---

Here's an alternative solution I would recommend you:

```
@Html.ActionLink(
    "Delete", 
    "Delete", 
    "AdminGroup", 
    new { id = item.AdminGroupId }, 
    new { id = "delete" }
)
```

and then in a separate javascript file AJAXify the link:

```
$(function() {
    $('#delete').click(function() {
        if (confirm('Delete?')) {
            var $link = $(this);
            $.ajax({
                url: this.href,
                type: 'DELETE',
                success: function(result) {
                    $link.parent().parent().remove();
                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: is there anyway to return this "$(this).parent().parent().remove();
: from the controller and execute it?

Comment: @Shane, in your controller you could `return JavaScript("$(this).parent().parent().remove();");` but be careful because `$(this)` might not point to what you could expect. Personally I wouldn't have the controller return javascript. I would handle it in the success callback.

Comment: @Darin, should I think that Darin doesn't recommend Ajax.ActionLink? thanks

Comment: AJAXifying the links doesnt work for the rows in the webgrid when executed in $(document).ready, where to do this?