# Icon to delete item from list in mvc3 list

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I have a mvc3 strong typed  partial view with a viewmodel containig a list of items.

I use a foreach-loop to genereate a table of this items.

There should be an icon on each line to delete that item from the list. the delete should be
a call to a service, to delete the item from the database and remove the item from the model, the refresh should be AJAX, so I don't need to refresh the whole page.

is ajax.actionlink the right thing to use or should I do something else?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use Ajax.ActionLink to call action for deleting items on the server. However you will need to refresh your table/grid additionaly calling other actions or just remove current row using javascript (if you don't have pager or something like this).

Comment: hm, could not the actionlink give back the updated list of elements?

Comment: yes, you can design your application to return updated data in ActionResult after deleting. If you have paginated results you can: a) re-render your results; b) just add next result row at the end of your table (it will save your performance a little). Anyway some additional coding required :)

Comment: thanks, that was what I hoped for. but: I start on controller/action, I would like to stay on that view, but the ajax.actionlink moves me to controller/deleteaction/id, instead of staying on controller/action and refreshing just a part of the view. how can I prevent that?

Comment: it's a lot of dicussions about Ajax.ActionLink [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878127/mvc3-ajax-actionlink)

Comment: thanks... I use a partialview, and it seems, that the scripts loaded in the view layout page are not accessible in the partialview. But why?   without the @Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" the @ajax.actionlink navigates you to a new page instead of replacing the target you specified.